# WebStorm 11 infinite indexing with Angular2

Tags: ide, angular, webstorm, node-modules, jetbrains-ide

Am using Angular2 under **WebStorm 11**. It seems that

***the indexing task*** goes on an infinite repetitive way even a loop and I noticed that it affects the quality of my app in runtime , moreover it seems charging  my CPU and my RAM,

Any propositions to deal with that ,

***what to do to stop/cancel this indexing charge ???***

[image]

Comment: Indexing and runtime behavior is quite unlikely to be related in any way. Did you `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart ...`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yeah of course am deleting caches from a time to another , i'm just noticing that this indexing task under webstorm didn't stop , it seems to repeat indefinetly and indirectlys it charges my cpu which causes finally a slowliness while my app is running , morover when running my app from a simple linux terminal and closing webstorm  my app goes much faster , i have readen few artciles and i saw that this indexing task causes the whole problem , i think

Comment: Might be similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19744 Sure indexing utilizes the CPU a lot and this slows down your entire machine.

Comment: thanks a lot but  since am using angular2 typescript what file should i change exactly , i didn't really understood very well the origin of problem and how resolve it exactely

Comment: Neither do I. Sorry I don't have a solution for your problem, just a pointer to a similar issue I run into.

Comment: thanks a lot , by the way i was informed that excluding nodes/modules from the control of version process in webstorm  (setting/version control/Ignored files) can help , i did it but it's seems to not be really the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1) Try to exclude build output directories.(Example :- tmp and dist directories in angular-cli base project).

[image]

Option 2) This is for angular release from 2.0.0-rc.1, Webstorme 2016.1 not working well with @angular2 and I hope this will fixed with next update. I have tried Webstorme EAP version 2016.2 and working well with angular2.

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP

Answer (score 0):

the problem was orginally from webstorm terminal's , some threads are charging the whole machine

so a temporary solution is to not use it's terminal , and use the linux terminal